# Make a play pause switch with html audio

Tags: html, audio, click

I'm looking for a way to do a play / pause action on click of an element.

Basically when you click and the track is not playing it plays and when it's playing and you click it stops.

So far I was looking for a solution like this but it seems to make a conflict between the play / pause action.

```
$('#feli').click(function() {
  feli.currentTime = 0;
  if (feli.play()) {
    feli.pause();
  } else {
    feli.play();;
  }
})
```

Any tips on how to do this simple action ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

check this code plz

```
$('#feli').click(function() {

  if (feli.play()) {
    feli.pause();
    feli.currentTime = 0;
  } else {
    feli.play();;
  }
});
```

Comment: Mmh kinda still the same problem :


`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()`

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution I put it here :

```
$('#feli').click(function() {
  if (feli.paused) {
    feli.currentTime = 0;
    feli.play();
  } else {
    feli.pause();
  }
})
```